# Converting multi-line String to Dict in Python

Tags: python, csv

I have the multi-line string taken from a csv file and am trying to convert it into a dict. I've written the piece of code below, which I would like to use, but don't know how to progress with it.

```
scsv = '''coupon,    months_to_maturity,    FACE_VALUE,
                0.3758,    12,    100,
                0.7287,    24,    100,
                1.0894,    36,    100,
                1.4019,    48,    100,
                1.6542,    60,    100,
                1.8512,    72,    100,
                2.0034,    84,   100,
                2.1213,    96,    100,
                2.2141,    108,    100,
                2.2891,    120,    100,
                2.3516,    132,    100,
                2.4058,    144,    100,
                2.4543,    156,    100,
                2.4994,    168,    100,
                2.5423,    180,    100,
                2.5841,    192,    100,
                2.6253,    204,    100,
                2.6664,    216,    100,
                2.7076,    228,    100,
                2.7491,    240,    100,
                2.7908,    252,    100,
                2.8328,    264,    100,
                2.8751,    276,    100,
                2.9175,    288,    100,
                2.9601,    300,    100,
                3.0026,    312,    100,
                3.0451,    324,    100,
                3.0875,    336,    100,
                3.1296,    348,    100,
                3.1714,    360,    100,
             '''
f = StringIO(scsv)
reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
for row in reader:
    #Dont know what should go here
```

Thank You

Comment: You probably want to use [`csv.DictReader`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader) rather than `csv.reader`.

Comment: @dsh This would result in a `DictReader` Object though. Could you show how to implement this?

Comment: What keys do you want in your dict?  If it is the column title, remember that dicts are unordered.

Comment: @user131983 I updated my answer. Did it help?

Comment: @user131983 Yes, you would have a DictReader object, that would give you dicts instead of lists in your loop.  Then you can do whatever it is you want to do with the dicts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
import os
import csv
from StringIO import StringIO

scsv = """coupon,    months_to_maturity,    FACE_VALUE,
                0.3758,    12,    100,
                0.7287,    24,    100,
                1.0894,    36,    100,
                1.4019,    48,    100,
                1.6542,    60,    100,
                1.8512,    72,    100,
                2.0034,    84,    100,
                2.1213,    96,    100,
                2.2141,    108,    100,
                2.2891,    120,    100,
                2.3516,    132,    100,
             """

scsv = scsv.replace(' ','')  #remove white spaces
scsv = scsv.replace(',' + os.linesep, os.linesep) #remove commas at the end of the lines

f = StringIO(scsv)
reader = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter=',')
rows = [row for row in reader]

print rows[0]
# {'coupon': '0.3758', 'months_to_maturity': '12', 'FACE_VALUE': '100'}
```